# Assuming $\sigma$ is known, find a method of moments estimator of $\mu$. (Location-scale family of exponential distribution)

Tags: statistics

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be i.i.d. observations from a location-scale family of exponential distributions with the pdf $$f_X(x\mid \mu,\sigma)=\frac{1}{\sigma}\exp\left(-\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right), \quad x\geq \mu \text{ and } \sigma>0$$ Assuming that $\sigma$ is known, find a method of moments estimator of $\mu$.

Normally what I would have done is set the sample mean equal to the population mean (i.e. the first moment of the pdf). But I wonder is there a known first moment for this pdf? If not how do I go about doing the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\int_\mu^\infty x \exp\left(-\frac{x-\mu}\sigma\right) \, \frac{dx}\sigma = \int_0^\infty (\mu+\sigma w) \exp(-w)\,dw = \mu + \sigma\int_0^\infty we^{-w}\,dw.
$$
(The $\mu$ pulls out in that way because $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-w}\,dw = 1$.)
$$
\int_0^\infty w \Big(e^{-w}\,dw\Big) = \underbrace{\int w\,dv = wv-\int v\,dw}_{\text{integration by parts}} = \underbrace{\left.-we^{-w}\vphantom{\frac11}\right|_0^\infty - \int_0^\infty -e^{-w}\,dw}.
$$
The first term in the expression over the second underbrace is $0$, by L'Hopital's rule.  The second term --- the integral --- is readily seen to be $1$.

Comment: Just to satisfy my curiousity can you do this without integrating? Hence are there values you can lookup?

Comment: Certainly you can look up the fact that the exponential distribution with density $e^{-x}$ for $x>0$ has expected value $1$.  It follows that if you multiply by $\sigma$ and then add $\mu$, you get expected value $\sigma+\mu$. ${}\qquad{}$